# Xcode 8 : Auto Layout Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have few problems with the auto layout. It looks perfect in Xcode for every iPhone models, but when I try on my iPhone 5S, the buttons don't look same as with my main storyboard. It works perfectly only for iPhone 7 and 7 plus sizes.

[image]

I used "Reset to suggested constraints" function. The Tic tac toe board is imageView and I have 9 buttons on it. These buttons don't look properly for iPhone 5s and 4s sizes. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you give width and height constraints?

Comment: I tried to give equal height and width, but it didn't work. When I set the original height and with, it gets bigger for iPhone 5s.

Comment: you can make use of UIStackView control

Comment: You are supposed to get those buttons on tictactoe imageview right? Where do you want your buttons i.e, on intersections points?

Comment: you can see where are the buttons in my screenshot. They are all on the imageview. The selected one which is in the screenshot is UIButton.

Comment: Most likely the problem lies in your constraints, control your constraints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the board you can user a view with black background color and for the buttons, put the buttons inside the board view by giving their height and width according to the height and width of the view. For example, button's height should be equal to (1/3 of view's height- (the spacing between the button)/2) and similarly do this for the width.

For the position of the buttons, position them to horizontal and vertical to board view and change the constraints multiplier accordingly(may be 1/2 for the first button , 1 for the center button and 3/2 for the third button) and similarly do this for the vertical position of the button.

Set the board view constraint to the main view, so now whenever the screen size changes your buttons and view will automatically be adjusted.

If you didn't understand my answer or need more clarity or help, just comment on this tagging me.

Comment: I made a similar layout for the calculator app if you need I can send you the project.

Comment: Thanks! I did what you said and it worked, but still I have few constraint error when I simulate the app. And It would be good if you send your project. I can learn more things with your project I guess.